# Efficient queue in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, haskell, list, queue

How can I efficiently implement a list data structure where I can have 2 views to the head and end of the list, that always point to a head a tail of a list without expensive calls to reverse.
i.e:

```
start x = []
end x = reverse start -- []
start1 = [1,2,3] ++ start
end start1 -- [3,2,1]
```

end should be able to do this without invoking 'reverse' but simply looking at the given list from the perspective of the list being in reverse automatically. The same should hold if I create new lists from concatenations to start.

Comment: In Haskell you cannot change values. `start` will always be the empty list, and `end` will always be the `reverse` of that (the empty list). If you want to keep state, you should look at the State monad.

Comment: correction: by update I mean rebind.

Comment: @Absolute: what you call it doesn't change the ultimate truth that you can't *change* things (`IO` monad notwithstanding) in Haskell. You can't rebind things.

Comment: @Martinho: by change I mean create a new one based on an old one and assign it to a new name, not sure why that isn't clear.

Comment: Because you didn't make that clear. Update and rebind can mean different things.

Comment: I *highly* recommend Purely Functional Datastructures mentioned by Apocalisp. There are quite a few "aha" moments in that book.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could always just use `Data.Sequence`.

Alternatively, a well-known implementation of a purely functional queue is to use two lists. One for enqueue and another for dequeue. Enqueue would simply cons with the enqueue list. Dequeue takes the head of the dequeue list. When the dequeue list is shorter than the enqueue list, refill it by reversing the enqueue list. See Chris Okasaki's [Purely Functional Datastructures.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/students/okasaki.pdf)

Even though this implementation uses `reverse`, the amortized time cost of this is insignificant asymptotically. It works out so that for every enqueue, you incur a time debt of Θ(1) for the dequeue list refill. The expected time of a dequeue is therefore at most twice that of an enqueue. This is a constant factor, so the worst-case cost of both operations is O(1).

Comment: Its insignificant *only* if used ephemerally. If your application depends on persistence, then its wholly possible to run into that O(n) case everytime you access your queue.

Comment: @Juliet With the use of laziness and memoization, the amortized bound is still O(1) while keeping the persistence

Comment: @Yuhta can you show an example using laziness and memoization?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Not really an example, but you can think about something like this: the reason when immutable queue used persistently would cause O(n) amortized bound is because multiple threads would reverse the same back list in the queue multiple times.  But if we have some mechanism to memoize the result of reversion, then after the first thread reverse the back list, the rest threads just need to retrieve the result of the first without paying the price of reversion.

Comment: I do think an example is needed, it seems pretty non trivial to have that caching work in all cases. For example if you have `Deque` `a` that is about to require a list reversal on the next pop, then inserting a new element will not change that fact but in any simple implementation it will break the cache (since you are essentially operating on the tail of the cached reversed list, which is O(n)). So you can insert n elements to create n different `Deque`s, then pop from them all. With a smart enough implementation it might work, but it probably won't be easy.

Answer (score 8):

This question appears as the third result on the first page while I google `Haskell queue`, but the information previously given is misleading. So, I feel there is a need to clarify a few things. (And the first search result is a blog post which contains a careless implementation...)

Everything below is basically from Okasaki's paper, [Simple and efficient purely functional queues and deques](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming/article/simple-and-efficient-purely-functional-queues-and-deques/7B3036772616B39E87BF7FBD119015AB) in 1995 or his [book](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/computer-science/programming-languages-and-applied-logic/purely-functional-data-structures?format=PB&isbn=9780521663502).

Okay, let's begin.

1. A persistent queue implementation with amortised *O(1)* time complexity is possible. The trick is to reverse the list representing the rear part of a queue as long as the front part is long enough to amortise the cost of `reverse` operation. So, instead of reversing the rear part when the front part is empty, we reverse it when the front part is shorter than the rear part. The following code is from the appendix of Okasaki's book

   ```
   data BQueue a = BQ !Int [a] !Int [a]

   check :: Int -> [a] -> Int -> [a] -> BQueue a
   check lenf fs lenr rs =
     if lenr <= lenf 
     then BQ lenf fs lenr rs 
     else BQ (lenr+lenf) (fs ++ reverse rs) 0 [] 

   head :: BQueue a -> a
   head (BQ _ []    _ _) = error "empty queue"
   head (BQ _ (x:_) _ _) = x

   (|>) :: BQueue a -> a -> BQueue a 
   (BQ lenf fs lenr rs) |> x = check lenf fs (lenr + 1) (x:rs)

   tail :: BQueue a -> BQueue a
   tail (BQ lenf (x:fs) lenr rs) = check (lenf-1) fs lenr rs
   ```
2. And why is this amortised *O(1)* even used *persistently*? Haskell is lazy, so `reverse rs` does not actually happen until it is needed. To force `reverse rs`, it has to take *|`fs`|* steps before reaching the `reverse rs`. If we repeat `tail` before reaching the suspension `reverse rs`, then the result will be memorised so at the second time it takes only *O(1)*. On the other hand, if we use the version before placing the suspension `fs ++ reverse rs`, then again it has to go through `fs` steps before reaching `reverse rs`. A formal proof using (modified) Banker's method is in Okasaki's book.
3. The answer by @Apocalisp

   > When the dequeue list is empty, refill it by reversing the enqueue list

   is the implementation in Ch 5 of his book with a warning in the very beginning

   > Unfortunately, the simple view of amortization presented in this chapter breaks in the presence of persistence

   Okasaki described his amortised *O(1)* persistent queue in Ch 6.
4. So far, we have been talking about amortised time complexity only. It is actually possible to eliminate amortisation completely to achieve the worst-case *O(1)* time complexity for *persistent queue*. The trick is that  `reverse` has to be forced incrementally every time a de/enqueue is called. The actual implementation is a bit hard to explain here, though.

Again, everything is in his paper already.

Answer (score 5):

Is [Data.Dequeue](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dequeue) what you are looking for?

(It doesn't have `reverse` but you can add it pretty easily and send a patch to the author.)

Comment: I am aware of the library, I just want to implement it myself as a fun thought experiment.

Comment: Or you can use the `Data.Sequence` module that is already in the standard library

Comment: Or... they can implement it themself as a fun thought experiment, like they established they wanted to do. And there is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a Haskell user, but I found [a blog post](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/02/08/haskell-queues-without-pointers) which claims to describe a Haskell queue that can be operated on in amortized constant time. It's based on a design from Chris Okasaki's excellent Purely Functional Data Structures.